# Autolayout uilabel autosize in tableView cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

Hello Nowadays I am trying to learn the `Autolayout`. I apologize in advance of asking a simple question.

[image]

I want to know how can I make the rightLabel which is LAHORE,PK shrinkable or autosize and also keep the Country label(left side) to its position. I have used some constraints but It then moves the Countrylabel to out of the screen. This is what I am doing in the cell and also please tell me if I am doing right or if not please tell me what would be the better way.

**Country**

1. I am first setting the countryLabel to `Center Vertically To TableViewCell`
2. I have set the left constraint to 14 points
3. I have locked the height to 22 points

**LAHORE,PK**

1. I have locked the height
2. set the countryLabel to `Center Vertically To TableViewCell`
3. I set the horizontal spacing between Lahore,Pk and Country
4. set right constraint to 0

The problem i am having is if larger text comes on the right side of the label then Country label which is on the left side moves out of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suspicious constraint to me is:

**LAHORE,PK**

3. I set the horizontal spacing between Lahore,Pk and Country

Delete it. Add this one:

**Trailing space of Lahore, Pk and superview**. Control and Drag from Lahore, Pk label to contentview of cell, and select `trailing space to container margin to zero.`

Setting a horizontal space betweeen lahore, pk and country pushes your label to the right outside of view.

Try it and let me know it there is still an issue.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do it is to put both in an horizontal stack view, then give the left label (the one which should not resize) higher hugging priority and compression resistance.

Of course you can also use old school auto layout still the important factors are hugging priority and compression resistance.

Comment: StackView is Available in iOS 9.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not set fixed height for views which has intrinsic content size, label is one of them.

There are two issues in the constraint you have currently set, one is, you have set HorizontalSpacing between Country two label's which must have some fixed points of constant, So what happening is when you run the app Auto layout is breaking the LeadingSpace constraint of First (left) label and moving it outside screen. So how can you prevent this from happening,

1. If you have two label horizontally align, then you must not set fixed point horizontal spacing between them, set the standard spacing instead as below,

[image]

2. Now you would see the Ambiguity in the constraints, as which label should have the priority to show the text in case if both the label have big text that could not be fitted on screen, so to resolved this change Horizontal Content Hugging Priority of one of the label from 251 to 252, and update the frame.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the final constraints are:

**Country Label:**

[image]

**Lahore.PK**

[image]

Hope this would help you.